# Interrupt number 100

Tags: c, virtualization, qemu

What is Interrupt 100 used for? I was going through the Qemu translation code `qemu/target-i386/translate.c` where I saw the reference.

```
static void gen_interrupt(DisasContext *s, int intno,
                      target_ulong cur_eip, target_ulong next_eip)
{
    if (intno == 100) {
        gen_helper_q_start_trace();         
        return;
    } else if (intno == 101) {
        gen_helper_q_end_trace();
        return;
    } else if (intno == 104 ) {
      gen_helper_q_hypercall_entry();    //Hypercall Entry
      return;
}
```

Comment: There isn't any code like this in the upstream QEMU gen_interrupt() function: http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-i386/translate.c;h=324103c88521a43aa42bf3d3f6b23ef6e6b94eb6;hb=6a928d25b6d8bc3729c3d28326c6db13b9481059#l2445

Are you looking at some fork of QEMU?

Comment: I am looking at qemu version 1.1.50

Comment: I just checked QEMU 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 and also did a 'git grep -G q_start_trace target-i386', and there is no sign of code like that in upstream QEMU. I think you're using a fork (of an old QEMU) with some local modifications, and you need to ask whoever wrote that fork what they're doing.

Comment: @PeterMaydell is there any interrupt named 100 in intel x86_64 architecture?